# WPF/Silverlight How To Calculate total cubic units/pixels in a control?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, graphics, vector-graphics

I have a scribbale inkpresenter in my silverlight app that I'm using multiple times in different shapes, I want  to calculate how much percent of the inkpresenter has been scribbled,

My problem is that since the shape of the ink presenter can be circular or poly I don't know how i can get the units/pixels there is available on the scribbable surface.

As far as i understand is that the actualWidth and actualHeight properties will only help me for rectangular shape by calculating

```
units = uielemnt.Actualwidth * uielement.ActualHeight
```

but for costum shapes I'm not sure how the actualWidth/Height are calculated.

Comment: "3D"?  "Cubic"?  Huh, looks positively like a 2D problem to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WPF Answer**

In WPF you can just use Geometry.Combine to combine the stroke geometries, then call GetArea on the combined geometry to get the total area covered.

**Silverlight Answer**

In Silverlight you don't have Geomerty.Combine or Geometry.GetArea, and you also don't have RenderTargetBitmap.  So in Silverlight I think you have to do the calculations yourself.

Here are the setup steps:

1. Convert the geometries to cubic bezier curves (approximate arcs, all else are exact)
2. Split all curves at their x minima and x maxima
3. Rearrange coordinates so each curve goes from low x to high x
4. Sort by x then y of first coordinate
5. Start at minimum x coordinate with no active curve segments

Here is the main loop:

1. Add any bezier curves that start at the current x coordinate to the active list
2. Remove any bezier curves that end at the current x coordinate from the active list
3. Compute intersections of active bezier curves.  Find next x coordinate of such intersection.
4. Let "end x" be earliest of next line intersection and next start or stop coordinate of a bezier curve
5. Compute area from current x to "end x" then set current to end
6. Repeat until "end x" reaches macimum x coordinate of any curve

Here is the inner loop that computes the area:

1. Go through active curves in increasing y.
2. Every time a curve is passed flip the "inside" bit for the original geometry for that curve.
3. Every time y changes any "inside" bit is set, compute the area between the previous bezier curve and the current one and add it to the grand total area

That's it.

**More details on Silverlight answer**

Formulas to convert segments of a PathGeometry into a cubic bezier approximation:

- BezierSegment:  Cubic control points are P0, P1, P2, P3  (no change)
- LineSegment:  Cubic control points are P0, P0, P1, P1
- QuadraticBezierSegment:  Cubic control points are P0, (P0+2P1)/3, (2P1+P2)/3, P2
- ArcSegment: Divide into octants and for each, compute unit tangent vectors T0, T1 at start & end pointing toward arc, generate control points (approximation) of P0, P0 + T0 * 4/3*(Sqrt(2)-1)*R, P1 + T1 * 4/3(Sqrt(2)-1)*R, P1, then modify with size and RotationAngle
- Poly...Segment:  Break into individual segments, then use above formulas on each

Computing intersections of active Bezier curves:

- Since the curves have already been split at their minima / maxima, each is a smooth, continuous function of x, you can use [these techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109364/bezier-clipping) to compute their intersection
- It can save some computation if you check y minima/maxima to see if there is any possible overlap before actually computing the intersection

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on "Convert the geometries to cubic bezier curves" and "Compute intersections of active bezier curves"?