# How to detect if an UIBezierPath intersects itself?

Tags: objective-c, ios, intersection, uibezierpath, cgpath

I have an user drawn UIBezierPath and I want to know if it intersects itself. 
Can anyone point me in a good direction for detecting this?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a good direction.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039229/checking-if-two-cubic-bezier-curves-intersect

Comment: Are you not simply checking if the UIBezierPath is closed or not by your question?

Comment: No, I do not want to check if it is closed. I just want to know if the path intersects itself. Say the user draws something like http://www.mathatube.com/images/pentagon-complex_1_.gif then we have an intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you build your path?  Is it just an accumulation of straight line segments?  If so you could keep a list of those (parallel to your UIBezierPath, that you use for rendering), and then perform line intersection tests.  It'll be O(N^2), though, in the naive implementation.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! For my purposes O(N^2) is more than enough!

Comment: can i get some code for this  line intersection test and this o(N^2)