# Intersection of two Bézier curves (or two curves and a line): code?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, bezier, curves

[Checking if two cubic Bézier curves intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039229/checking-if-two-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves-intersect) gives a link to http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch7.pdf .. sounds readable on first pass.. but it is not code.

I am wondering if someone has actually implemented this algorithm in any common programming language. I would be interested in some Javascript code (other languages OK) that can implement the algorithm using two cubic Bézier curves, or a Bézier curve and a straight line.

Comment: If you're asking about a specific algorithm, it'd be a good idea to mention which one in the title/post (the linked chapter contains more than one). The subdivision algorithm is implemented over at http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#curveintersection

Answer (score 0):

For a cubic Bézier curves and a straight line it probably easiest to use section 7.3 Intersection of a Parametric Curve and an Implicit Curve. You can write the straight line as `a x+b y+c=0`. If you Bézier curves in given by cubic p(t) and q(t) for x and y coords you can substitute those into the line equation. This gives a cubic in t which you can solve by your favourite root finding algorithm.

The similar question [Checking if two cubic Bézier curves intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039229/checking-if-two-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves-intersect?rq=1) has some good answers. In particular the first answer mentions the [asymptote library](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) which has code for all these. You can see the relevant source code at http://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/asymptote/path.cc including code for finding roots of a cubic.