# Checking if two Bezier curves collide

Tags: collision-detection, intersection, bezier

There are numerous questions on checking if two Bezier curves *intersect*, the most prominent being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039229/checking-if-two-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves-intersect). However, this answers the question of checking if

`B1(t1)=B2(t2)`

Where `B1` and `B2` are Bezier curves. We may thus have that `t1` is not `t2`. But I want to check for *collision*, that is

`B1(t)=B2(t)`

So they must intersect at the same time `t`. Is there an algorithm that can quickly detect this without having to go over all times `t`, i.e. is it possible to figure it out from just the control points?

Comment: Your case is actually simpler as you have a single variable for a single equation. While the referred topic had to find two variables for a single equation. A piece of paper or WolframAlpha may be your next stop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you think this will let you do: collisions and intersections are the same thing in geometric programming. Two curves intersection at the same `t` value is a special case, but it's _still_ an intersection, it's not suddenly something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your restriction means that you can just solve for `t` for a single dimension, then verify in all others. I.e. solve `Bx₁(t) = Bx₂(t)` since there's only one variable, and if that yields (a) `t` value(s) in the interval [0,1], plug the found value(s) into `By(t)` without needing to solve for anything, to see if you get another equality. If so, plug it into `Bz(t)` to verify, etc. etc. for however many dimensions your Bezier is defined for.

With the caveat that solving for `t` means you're performing root finding, which means that any fifth order expression or higher can't be solved symbolically (see the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) for why that is) and you'd have to "solve" for `t` using numerical analysis instead.

Although I'm not sure what doing this would get you: it's not a particularly useful constraint, and will conclude that "there is no collision" for almost every possible situation in which a human would conclude that there very much *is* a collision. You'd need to get otherworldly lucky for two arbitrary curves to coincide at the exact same `t` value. Or you'd have to use curves specifically *designed* to intersect at the same `t` value (in which case there's nothing to calculate, you already know they do, and where ;)