# SVG binary operation like difference

Tags: xml, html, svg

`clipPath` can be used to do intersection. But what about difference and other binary operations?

This is a list of binary operations in InkScape. How can I implement them using SVG?
[image]

Comment: You can export from incscape to svg to wee what is does. But i think it will create compleatly new shapes.

Comment: @AntiHeadshot Yes I did. And it does create new shapes.

Comment: Aparently its not possible without some additional code. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16248285/1875118) is an answer to a JavaScript library.

Comment: if you want to create new shapes a solution could be elaborating  the paths with JS; you can achieve the effect of intersection with clipPath but you may have problems with border..